# Creating methods in has-a relationships

Tags: java, class, methods

I have made a class, say Products, that looks like this:

```
public class Products{
       private String name;
       private Characteristics characteristics;
       //...
}
```

The class Characteristics looks like this:

```
public class Characteristics{
       private int id;
       private int price;
       private String weight;
       //...
}
```

(I know, the example is not that good, because all the attributes in the Characteristics class could be in the Products instead, but let's say that this is the way it should be.)

The main function looks like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
       ArrayList<Products> products = new ArrayList<>();
       //I have added 100 objects
       products.get(0).setName("tea");


}
```

How can also set values to the other attributes, on the Characteristics class?

A very naive way to do this was to write a method setPrice in the Products class, that calls a method with a same name in the Characteristics class. But this is also wrong, since I receive the well-known message: "non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context".

Is there any way to solve this problem? Or is it better to change the way classes are designed, i.e. to move every attribute from Characteristics class to Products class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `getter` and call methods on it

```
products.get(0).getCharacteristics().setId(1);
```

---

```
public class Product {
    // code
    public Characteristic getCharacteristics() {
        return this.characteristics;
    }
}

public class Characteristic {
    // code
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In your opinion, would you consider this as a program with a nice structure? I mean is it used among programmers, or it is an example of bad design that should be avoided? (I am asking only because I am still learning Java and I have not yet entirely understood Object Oriented Programming good design/programming principles.)

Comment: @George In my opinion (this is my own opinion), it is always good, if it stays logical, to divide your objects into subclasses like you did here. Having too much fields within a class can become quickly messy.

Comment: I tried your code, but I am unable to write something like this: System.out.println(products.get(0).getId()); I have added a getter method in Characteristics class, but it isn't working...

Comment: @George `public int getId(){ return this.id; }` Like this? Plus, you have to first call the char. object `products.get(0).getCharacteristics().getId()`

Comment: I tried that before, but in `System.out.println(products.get(0).getId());` I receive a "cannot find symbol" error. It seems that the compiler cannot recognize the getId() method.